# How can I change fontSize in tailwind.config in ReactJs, fontSize will come from API?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm using Tailwind and React, now I need to set font size dynamically from API.

tailwind.config code:

```
 plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addBase }) {
      addBase({
        'html' : {fontSize:"10px"} //this font size should come from API
      })
    })
  ],
```

API response:

```
{fontSize:"14px",fontFamily:'poppins'}
```

How can I make fontSize dynamically?

Comment: Tailwind runs in built-time, api request runs in run-time. Just set the font size using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using CSS variables and manually setting that variable using JS once the response is received from the server.

CSS variables are set on the document (HTML) object itself, so we can easily change it using JS later by accessing the style object like so:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--variable-name", value);
```

1. In your `tailwind.config.js` set the `fontSize` to a CSS variable instead.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
 plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addBase }) {
      addBase({
        'html' : {fontSize:"var(--html-font-size)"} //this font size should come from API
      })
    })
  ],
```

2. In your .js file, when you receive the response from the API, update the value of the `--html-font-size` variable like so:

```js
// script.js

// call your API
async function getFontSizeFromServer() {
  try {
    const req = await fetch("url");
    const res = req.json();
   
    // if you got a successful response from your API
    if(req.status === 200 && res) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--html-font-size", res.fontSize)
    }
  }
  catch(err){}
}
```

You can do something similar for the `fontFamily` if you want by creating another variable and setting that as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey this is working fine...

Comment: how to do it in nativewind?